# SQL Limit on "WHERE X IN (...)"

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I've got some data I'd like to pull off our SQL server.

This old database does not have any primary keys associated with it, so pulling data is like querying an Excel spreadsheet (what it actually originated as years ago).

I need to run reports on this data, though.

Currently, I get a list of distinct serial numbers for a given time period, then pull all of the records for a given serial number. For a 1-month time frame, this can be 1500 to 3000 serial numbers. The serial number field is formatted as `char(20)`, even though the serial numbers are only 15 characters long.

**BEGIN UPDATE**

- There are typically 5 to 15 entries in this table per `Serial_Number`.
- There are at most 10 machines writing data to this table, so identical `Date_Time` values are possible

**END UPDATE**

This process takes a while, but between different serial numbers in the list, I am able to update the Windows Form with a Progress Bar so management knows something is happening and about how much longer to expect.

I am always trying to make this query run faster.

Now, I am thinking about pulling the data I need using a `WHERE` clause such as:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM Table1
WHERE Serial_Number IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT Serial_Number
  FROM Table1
  WHERE Date_Time Between @startDate AND @endDate
)
```

My question is: Are there any issues I could run into with this, particularly because we have so many distinct serial numbers during a given time frame.

And, of course, you know someone in Management is going to try running a year's worth of data when they are bored! Then, they are going to try running data since Jesus was born, just because they've got nothing better to do.

**Restate Question:** Is there a limit to the `WHERE` clause's `IN` method that limits the number of items I can pass in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is **no way to tell** what the maximum length of the `WHERE X IN (...)` can be.

For now, this is the answer.

If, at some later point in time, someone comes along and finds something to the contrary, please post that answer and I will mark it as such.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 2):

Index Serial_Number and Date_Time in Table1 (with separate indexes, not a single compound index) and this should perform fairly well for you unless the table is really truly ginormous.

You might get a little more speed with one index on Serial_Number and the second on (Date_Time, Serial_Number).  That second index covers the sub query, allowing it to be answered from the index alone.

Note: I'm suggesting indexes, not primary keys, which don't require uniqueness.

Comment: Generally, there are multiple entries per serial number. The Date_Time parameter could possibly serve as an index, but we have 10 different machines dumping data into the same table. There could be duplicates.

Comment: @jp2code you can (and should) define indexes on the columns you need, doesn't matter if they're unique or not, what Larry said, just adding those indexes alone should make your queries go from 1 minute to like an instant

Comment: Duplicates don't matter.  The indexes don't need to be unique.  Index (Date_Time, Serial_Number) to speed the nested query and (Serial_Number) alone to speed the main query.

Comment: I would guess [CREATE INDEX](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp) has already been done. I've been working on this data for 5 years, but it is much older than that. How would I check?

Comment: PS: I believe you're confusing indexes with primary keys.  Primary keys generally create an index to aid in enforcement, but they are conceptually different things.

Comment: @jp2code: You can check using SSMS or any other tool that can show you the structure of table.

Comment: Would that be the `Identity Specification (Is Identity)` on the given column?

Comment: No, that specifies that the column autonumbers itself.  The indexes are listed separately from the columns.  In SSMS there's a node "under" the table node for indexes and one for keys.  Alternatively, if you "script" the table to see the SQL Create statements that go into making it up, you can see if there are any CREATE INDEX statements.

Comment: So, is there a limit to how many parameters can be passed to the `IN` method of the `WHERE` clause? (I updated my question to restate this)

Comment: There is no *practical* limit, but there are other questions on StackOverflow that cover the issue of maximum statement length in SQL Server (including in this exact situation in which an IN clause is growing in size).

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the naive case where there are no indexes (which it sounds like is your case) you're going to have to scan over all the rows in `Table1` to perform the `DISTINCT` on `Serial_Number` anyway.  So I'm not sure it's going to help you much.

I would highly recommend the following:

- Use the execution plan to determine what's going on in your query, and
- Use that information to add some relevant indexes to speed your operations.

Just from what we see here, it sounds like `Date_Time` would be a good candidate for a clustered index in `Table1`.

Edit:

To make a nonunique clustered index as I describe above, you can use the following:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table1_Date_Time
ON Table1 (Date_Time)
```

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258260(v=sql.80).aspx)

This will reorder your table such that all rows are sorted in Date_Time order.  Further work with the execution plan will help identify other indexes that may greatly help your performance, depending on the exact types of queries you run.

Comment: I placed some updated text above. How would I create a clustered index?

Comment: I looked at my table, and it appears the Serial_Number has already been added as an index. I could add the date, though. **But:** Is there a limit to how many parameters can be passed to the `IN` method of the `WHERE` clause? (I updated my question to restate this)

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no limit.  Are you talking about hardcoding (or generating) a big list of the exact parameter values you want?  If the list is reasonably small that would work.  If it's large, you might run into query parsing overhead issues.  By all means, further clarify and I'll try to help.

Comment: My `SELECT DISTINCT Serial_Number` code will easily return 1500 values for any given month. There is no logic in place that prevents someone from trying to run this query over a year or more, though.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I see no benefit to the `WHERE` clause as it is written.

You use an expensive inner query, but don't do anything meaningful with the results. I don't even see you getting the `Serial_Number` in the results anywhere. However, based on your question, it does sound like you need it.

I don't see the need for the `DISTINCT` keyword for `Serial_Number`, since the duplicates would not be eliminated in the results in the outer query.

What is wrong with doing this?

```
SELECT Serial_Number, Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM Table1
WHERE Date_Time Between @startDate AND @endDate
```

This should do the same thing as your original query. But it would eliminate the expensive nested query.

Just put an index on `Date_Time` and it should work. This would also eliminate the need for the index on `Serial_Number`.

Comment: My main question is if there was some limit to the number of items I can place in that `WHERE` clause's `IN` method. If I don't select `DISTINCT`, then I will easily have 10 times as many serial numbers in the `IN` method. Is SQL smart enough to eliminate the duplicates or will it search them as well? I don't know.

Comment: And, yes. I use the `Serial_Number` field. It would be one of my columns returned. I simply used `Col1`, `Col2` and `Col3` to indicate generic column names.

Comment: Finally, just because a serial number was tested between `@startDate` and `@endDate` does not mean this was the first time this item was tested. We have a bonus system in place that rewards items that pass test criteria their first time. If an item sits in the warehouse for 6 months then gets retested before being shipped out, it would appear that an employee should be rewarded based on your query.